# What is the most efficient way to clean currency data in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, currency

This is more of an open ended question since I'm not looking for a one particular code response. I have an example dataset, which is just a manually modified snippet of the set I am using. What I want to know is, for you more experienced R data analysts, how would you approach cleaning this data? Prioritising speed and efficiency (in terms of real time and computing time), what steps would you take and why, and which R packages are most useful? With enough googling and effort I have figured it out myself, but I'm certain my solutions are inelegant and inefficient. Do you have any little known tricks or functions that can fix multiple problems at once?

Imagine this is sales data pulled from a website with discounts and number of product ratings. Initially, every column is of **character** type: Note - I made it annoyingly messy on purpose

| price | discounted_price | discount_percent | rating_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USD499 | USD176.63 | 65% | 15,188 |
| USD299 | USD399 | 25% | 34,899 |
| 19900 $ | 11,499 $ | 42 | 4703 |
| $475 | $309 | 35% | 4,26,973 |
| $ 22,900 | $ 13490 | 41% | 16,299 |
| 699.99USD | 263.28USD | 62 | 450 |
| $899 | $349 | 61% | 149 |
| USD1999 | USD1,299 | 35 | 590 |

The clean table should look like this:

| price | discounted_price | discount_percent | rating_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $499.00 | $176.63 | 65% | 15,188 |
| $299.00 | $399.00 | 25% | 34,899 |
| $19,900.00 | $11,499.00 | 42% | 4,703 |
| $475.00 | $309.00 | 35% | 426,973 |
| $22,900.00 | $13,490.00 | 41% | 16,299 |
| $699.99 | $263.28 | 62% | 450 |
| $899.00 | $349.00 | 61% | 149 |
| $1,999.00 | $1,299.00 | 35% | 590 |

Tasks to perform:

- Make all price values in the format 0,000.00 with a comma separator for bigger values
- Make all price values have a $ prefix
- Make percentage column in the format xx%
- Make rating_count in the format 0,000

Edit: Removed task to make all columns numeric as it didn't make sense

Comment: `Make all columns numeric instead of character type` --> your desired output is all strings, you're defeating your own requirement.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right site to issue challenges. It's better to ask clear, focused programming questions. Whether or not something is "elegant" is very subjective. And whether or not something is efficient really depends on what exactly you are testing. You can optimize for different desired outcomes.

Comment: @MrFlick Apologies, I'm new around here, where might be a better place to pose this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discarding your *"all columns numeric"* constraint, since your expected output is all string, this is easily addressed with `scales` in a `dplyr` pipe:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(scales) # dollar, percent, comma
quux %>%
  mutate(
    across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(gsub("[^-0-9.]", "", .))),
    discount_percent = discount_percent/100,
    across(c(price, discounted_price), ~ dollar(.)),
    discount_percent = percent(discount_percent, accuracy=1),
    rating_count = comma(rating_count)
  )
#        price discounted_price discount_percent rating_count
# 1    $499.00          $176.63              65%       15,188
# 2    $299.00          $399.00              25%       34,899
# 3 $19,900.00       $11,499.00              42%        4,703
# 4    $475.00          $309.00              35%      426,973
# 5 $22,900.00       $13,490.00              41%       16,299
# 6    $699.99          $263.28              62%          450
# 7    $899.00          $349.00              61%          149
# 8  $1,999.00        $1,299.00              35%          590
```

If you want to do any analysis or numeric processing, then separate this into two stages:

```r
quux %>%
  mutate(
    across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(gsub("[^-0-9.]", "", .))),
    discount_percent = discount_percent/100
  ) %>%
  # do your analysis/calculations here
  mutate
    across(c(price, discounted_price), ~ dollar(.)),
    discount_percent = percent(discount_percent, accuracy=1),
    rating_count = comma(rating_count)
  )
```

If you have any other columns that might already be numeric, you may want to replace `everything()` with `where(is.character)`. (You can use it anyway if you choose.)

This can also easily be done with base R or `data.table`. The `scales` package does make most of the formatting much easier.

You can generalize the formatting a bit if you have multiple columns not present in this example, using

```r
quux %>%
  mutate(
    across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(gsub("[^-0-9.]", "", .))), 
    across(ends_with("percent"), ~ ./100)
  ) %>%
  # do your analysis/calculations here
  mutate(
    across(ends_with("price"), ~ dollar(.)), 
    across(ends_with("percent"), ~ percent(., accuracy=1)), 
    across(ends_with("count"), ~ comma(.))
  )
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(price = c("USD499", "USD299", "19900 $", "$475", "$ 22,900", "699.99USD", "$899", "USD1999"), discounted_price = c("USD176.63", "USD399", "11,499 $", "$309", "$ 13490", "263.28USD", "$349", "USD1,299"), discount_percent = c("65%", "25%", "42", "35%", "41%", "62", "61%", "35"), rating_count = c("15,188", "34,899", "4703", "4,26,973", "16,299", "450", "149", "590")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```